# OldStyle numbers, the Fira Sans font and the siunitx package: incorrect % symbol

Tags: xetex, symbols, siunitx, oldstylenums, mathspec

I am working on a document where I regularly use percentages. For that I'd like to use the `siunitx` package so that I can write `\SI{56}{\%}`.
I also prefer to use OldStyle (or Lining) numbers.
Currently I'm using XeLaTeX and the Mozilla Fira Sans font and all seems to go well, except the % symbol which seems to come from the default Computer Modern font.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[]{mathspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle,BoldFont={Fira Sans SemiBold}]{Fira Sans Book}
\setsansfont[Numbers=OldStyle,BoldFont={Fira Sans SemiBold}]{Fira Sans Book}
\setmonofont{Fira Mono}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek){Fira Sans Book}
\setmathsf[]{Fira Sans Book}


\usepackage[]{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item Some numbers in text mode: 1234567890.

\item  Some numbers using the \texttt{siunitx} package:
  \SI{1234567890}{m/s}. This works well.

\item However, specifying percentages doesn't use the \% symbol I
  would like: \SI{24.5}{\%} or \SI{24.5}{\percent}. Compared to
  regular text: 24.5 \%.
\item Another font check: SI \SI{9}{million} vs regular 9 million.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Any idea how to tell the `mathspec` package (or something else) to take the % symbol from the Fira Sans font? I also tried the `detect-all` option of the `siunitx` package, but that didn't work either.

Strangely enough, if I remove the `Numbers=OldStyle` option for the fonts and use `detect-all` for `siunitx` the correct symbol is used:
[image: without OldStyle numbers]

Comment: Does it help if you do `\SI[mode=text]{24.5}{\%}` or `\SI[mode=text]{24.5}{\percent}`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Adding `[mode=text]` indeed works. Although it will be a bit tedious add that for each percentage. Time to do some RegExp replacing ;-). Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  It depends on your document, but I tend to do `\sisetup{mode=text}` in the preamble if I use a font with no proper math support.  Otherwise, use the answer provided by @egreg.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redefine `\%` to do the right thing:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[]{mathspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle,BoldFont={Fira Sans SemiBold}]{Fira Sans Book}
\setsansfont[Numbers=OldStyle,BoldFont={Fira Sans SemiBold}]{Fira Sans Book}
\setmonofont{Fira Mono}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek){Fira Sans Book}
\setmathsf[]{Fira Sans Book}

\usepackage[]{siunitx}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\%}{\ifmmode\textnormal{\symbol{`\%}}\else\symbol{`\%}\fi}
\DeclareSIUnit{\percent}{\%}


\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item Some numbers in text mode: 1234567890.

\item  Some numbers using the \texttt{siunitx} package:
  \SI{1234567890}{m/s}. This works well.

\item However, specifying percentages doesn't use the \% symbol I
  would like: \SI{24.5}{\%} or \SI{24.5}{\percent}. Compared to
  regular text: 24.5 \%.
\item Another font check: SI \SI{9}{million} vs regular 9 million.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @egreg! That's even better than the `[mode=text]` suggestion by @Arash Esbati.